# Integrate third party android SDK in ionic v2

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using a third party android SDK for some functionalities (card reader, QR code scanner), I am able to use it in the native Android app, now I want to create a hybrid app on ionic and I want to use that 3rd party library.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I got the answer and it was pretty straight forward

If you have exported your module / plugin like

```
module.exports = new YourPluginJavaClass();
```

then you will be able to use it in your Ionic application as

```
(window as any).YourPluginJavaClass.yourFunction();
```