# ionic: add own cordova plugin

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic3

I modified an existing cordova plugin and want to integrate it now into my application.

I already created a link to my source directory

```
cordova plugin add --link ~/path/to/plugin
```

but now I can not find my plugin in my project. I suggest, that the plugin needs to be build?

Is it needed to modify my package.json?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the plugin to project:

   ```
   ionic cordova plugin add [plugin]
   ```

   [Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/plugin/)
2. Install and save the plugin:

   ```
   npm install --save [plugin]
   ```

   [Example](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/)

Comment: This would pull the official version and is not the answer to my question

Comment: You can whether add the plugin with --link as you already did or you can add  it like I described. What do you mean, you can not "find" it?

Comment: there is nothing that I can import like Camera from "@ionic-native/camera"

Comment: When you --link it, you probably need to import it from there

Comment: Then it says - it's not a module

Answer (score 1):

This is related to [stackoverflow/questions/30345035](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345035/how-to-add-a-local-cordova-plugin-with-ionic-ionic-2-ionic-3)

Since you modify existing plugin there is possibility that you didn't modify it right. Also there is possibility that plugin is not working for specific platform version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to add your own cordova plugin in Ionic v2 here can be your solution.

If you have exported your module / plugin like

```
module.exports = new YourPluginJavaClass();
```

then you will be able to use it in your Ionic application as

```
(window as any).YourPluginJavaClass.yourFunction();
```

Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720151/integrate-third-party-android-sdk-in-ionic-v2/41034872#41034872) as well

Hope this helps.